# Keyboard not showing up

Tags: ios, ios7, uialertview, uikeyboard

I have an application which prompt the user to enter a password through a popup textbox.  The keyboard is not showing up for the textbox like it had in previous versions of iOS.  Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.  I believe this is the snippet of code dealing with the password entry functionality.

```
- (void)showPreferencesPasswordPrompt {
InputAlertView * inputAlert = [[InputAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"browser_preferences_password_alert_title", nil)
                                                            message:NSLocalizedString(@"browser_preferences_password_alert_message", nil)
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"cancel", nil)
                                                  otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"ok", nil), nil];

inputAlert.tag = PREFERENCES_PASSWORD_TAG;
inputAlert.textField.secureTextEntry = YES;

[inputAlert show];
[inputAlert release];
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is over a year old, but I just had the same problem and my solution might help someone else.  In my case, a setting on the simulator was inadvertently turned on: **Hardware > Keyboard > Connect Hardware Keyboard**.

Once I de-selected this setting, the virtual keyboard began appearing as expected.

Comment: Responding to old questions is fine I think but in this case I am not sure the OP is talking about the `iOS Simulator`?

Answer (score 1):

AlertViews need to have their text fields set up differently with ios 7.  Something like this:

```
    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:NSLocalizedString(@"Rename List", @"Rename List") delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"Cancel") otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK"), nil];
    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    alertTextField_ = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
    alertTextField_.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;
    alertTextField_.placeholder = list.name;
    [alert show];
    [alertTextField_ becomeFirstResponder];
```